# Grafana show MySQL connections count

Tags: mysql, connection, grafana, status

How to write a query run by a dashboard to get the MySQL active connections?

There are MySQL queries like:

```
show status like 'Connections';
```

or

```
show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

that give the expected result when used from MySQL console client

but how to use them if Grafana queries look like that:

```
SELECT
  date_time AS "time",
  interesting_data AS "measurement"
FROM test
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(date_time)
ORDER BY date_time
```

Since there is no table with date/time stamp I could want to query I changed `date_time` to NOW():

```
  SELECT
  NOW() AS "time",
  6 as "connections";
```

and the dashboard displayed hardcoded number, but how to use real queries to get a real connection number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query `information_schema.processlist`:

```
SELECT 
  NOW() AS "time", 
  count(*) AS "count"
FROM information_schema.processlist;
```

Comment: works well :)
do you have any idea how to approach `show status like 'Connections';` to be displayed as well?

Comment: Try in the table panel.